# Bad \line or \vector when attempt to use `\layout`

Tags: errors, texlive

When I attempt to use `\layout` with the MWE below I get:

> LaTeX Error: Bad \line or \vector argument.

Commenting out `\layout` works fine and the file list is:

```
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  lipsum.sty    2014/07/27 v1.3 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
  layout.sty    2000/09/25 v1.2c Show layout parameters
```

So, do I for some reason have an old package?  I and using TeXLive2014 and just ran TeXLive utility to update all packages.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{layout}

\listfiles
\layout
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Weird error but you need to put the command *in* the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move`\layout` after `\begin{document}`.

[image]

Comment: Wow!! Very embarrassing!! Especially considering that I have answered numerous questions using `\layout`!!!

Comment: @PeterGrill, after a hard work to type and format your question it would be a fault to delete it. Keep it open.

Comment: Yeah, I am not a fan of deleting questions as I probably won't be the last person to make that mistake. Am hoping that my shame will help others. :-)

Comment: Once I was testing `minted` and it took me almost one day to discover that someone had saved a bad `minted.sty` file on my home folder and I was testing and testing and nothing... fortunately I found that old style file.

Comment: :-) I never work with TeX in my home directory - gets too cuttered. But of course same problem can happen in another directory.

Comment: @sigur What is it exactly that `\layout` needs after `\begin{document}`?

Comment: @JonathanKomar, the command `\layout` is provided by the same name package. But it should be used in body document and produces that figure with the layout of the document.

Comment: I use the \layoutcommand in the text body after \begin{document} but I also get this error.